# Display Latest Row in MYSQL for each enrollment by an account number

Tags: mysql

I need to generate a list of entries using the select below. The list needs to be the latest entry for each. When I try using GROUP BY, it still doesn't seem to get me the latest entry for each field. I have tried using MAX(ID) and MAX(CONDATE), but that just seems to populate only that field with the latest data, while the other fields are not from the same row.

If I have multiple entries with the same email, LDC_ACCT, etc., how can I generate the list to show just the latest of multiple entries by each LDC_ACCT?

```
    select 
    ID,
    email,
    LDC_ACCT,
    LDC_KEY,
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    ServiceAddress1,
    ServiceAddress2,
    CITY,
    STATE,
    ZIP,
    date(ContractExpirationDate) AS 'ContractExpiration',
    date(CONTDATE) AS 'LatestEnrollmentDate',
    ldc_last4
    from elec_cust
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to have any aggregate function (and don't plan to) in your SELECT statement, this works too :

```
 SELECT
    t.ID,
    t.email,
    t.LDC_ACCT,
    t.LDC_KEY,
    t.FIRST_NAME,
    t.LAST_NAME,
    t.ServiceAddress1,
    t.ServiceAddress2,
    t.CITY,
    t.STATE,
    t.ZIP,
    date(t.ContractExpirationDate) AS 'ContractExpiration',
    date(t.CONTDATE) AS 'LatestEnrollmentDate',
    t.ldc_last4
    FROM (SELECT * FROM elec_cust ORDER BY ID DESC) t
    GROUP BY t.LDC_ACCT
```

Comment: Thanks Aurelien - question: what is does the "t." refer to in your answer?

Comment: Thanks - that got me to where I needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get the latest information for the LDC_ACCT. The latest information is considered as the one with the most recent CONTDATE.

```
SELECT * FROM
elec_cust a,
(
    SELECT LDC_ACCT, MAX(CONTDATE) AS MAX_CONT_DATE
    FROM elec_cust
    GROUP by LDC_ACCT
) b
WHERE 
    a.LDC_ACCT = b.LDC_ACCT 
    AND a.CONTDATE = b.MAX_CONT_DATE;
```

Answer (score -1):

First get the list of the latest ID values for each distinct value of LDC_ACCT.

```
       SELECT MAX(ID) ID, LDC_ACCT FROM table GROUP BY LDC_ACCT
```

Then get those rows from the table.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE
     ID IN ( SELECT MAX(ID) ID, LDC_ACCT FROM table GROUP BY LDC_ACCT)
```

This assumes that rows with higher ID values are *later* than those with lower ID values.